# How can we unset all names in a section (Mercurial)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, mercurial, hgrc

Our team are using mercurial both on Windows and Linux, 
and many members have their own customized `.hgrc` files in their 
home directories in order to convert source code;
We're using `.hgrc` files (in home directory) with non-empty `[encode]/[decode]` sections.

Recently, we created a new repository for a project in which encoding 
of text files plays a key role.  We have multiple files with same 
extension, in various encoding forms.  (e.g., .html files in Shift-JIS, euc-japan-unix, utf8, and so on.)

In order to preserve encoding forms in this repository, 
**we want to unset all names in a section**.

Currently, we are dealing with this issue by 
listing all extension names that may be listed in `.hgrc` file in home directories, in `hgrc` file of the project.

So our `hgrc` file looks like this:

```
[encode]
%unset **.js
%unset **.txt
%unset **.html

[decode]
%unset **.js
%unset **.txt
%unset **.html
```

This method works, but is painful. (we might have to add more extension names to unset in the future.)
Is there any way to unset all names in a section, without pain?

Comment: Do you use editors which *change* the encoding or line endings of existing files? If not, then I don't see how those sections are needed at all... They are only needed if you want to commit them with a different encoding than you work on them. If your editors are bad or badly configured, I suggest to change rather those...

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  We don't use such editors, but our legacy system to build c++ programs, which runs on our Linux server, does not allow us to discard our (somewhat dirty) `.hgrc` files in our home directory.